# How to retrieve file from /home/runner/XXXXX in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to build maven project with GitHub Actions, and after the job running, I get the message

> Please refer to /home/runner/work/testDemoAPI/testDemoAPI/mymeeave/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.

Do you know how to retrieve data from `/home/runner/work/xxxxx`?

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      run:  mvn clean test
```

Answer (score 6):

Upload it as an artifact, afterwards it can be downloaded from the GitHub UI or via the GitHub API:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Build with Maven
      run:  mvn clean test

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: surefire-reports
        path: mymeeave/target/surefire-reports/**
```

See https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact for documentation.

Comment: @fdiori that's good to hear. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: What if the build fails? The Upload artifact won't be executed and the logs that are stored in /home/runner/work are lost.

Comment: @aurel-LX you can add the line `if: ${{ !cancelled() }}` in the *upload artifact* step to upload regardless of failure or success.

Answer (score 0):

You can save files to `/home/runner` and access them in later actions.

An example from my project which:

- Runs tests
- Store logs always and test failed file
- Upload logs as artefact
- Exits if the test was failure

  ```
  - name: Run web E2E tests
    run: |
      set +e
      yarn test-e2e
      result=$?
      if [ $result != 0 ]; then touch /home/runner/test-failed-web-e2e; fi
      kubectl logs $(kubectl get pods | grep backend | awk '{print $1}') > /home/runner/logs-backend.txt
      kubectl logs $(kubectl get pods | grep frontend | awk '{print $1}') > /home/runner/logs-frontend.txt

  - name: Upload logs
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
    with:
      name: logs-all
      path: /home/runner/logs-*.txt
      retention-days: 5

  - name: Propagate any E2E test failures
    run: |
      if [ -f /home/runner/test-failed-web-e2e ]; then exit 1; fi
  ```